# cordova image reference content:/// and file:///

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing an image upload module using cordova. I also need the reference to the image.
I tried 2 different plugins. Here are the issues I face.

1. https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser - I am able to choose the gallery and perform image upload, but it does not appear to return the correct url. It returns content:///…/some_id and I am not able to upload this file to the server
2. With plugin https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker, I am also able to open the gallery and upload images, but the actual file is returned, file:///.../file_name.jpg, which can be uploaded to the server. I need to be able to reference the file.
   Would appreciate if someone would provide the right pointers to solve the issues above. What am I doing wrong? Which one of these 2 plugins is prefered

Comment: `I need to be able to reference the file` I don't understand what you mean by this. Are you looking for a way to read and display the image in your app?

Comment: Yes, I am looking to display the image in my app, and also need to upload the image to the server, but I think content:/// file reference is not the correct reference to the file to upload, let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: The plugin should do 2 things - allow me to upload and display the image in my app, as well as providing a reference link for uploading to the server. The plugin with content:///file reference is not doing that. Can you help? Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: If you are looking to display the image in your HTML using the `<IMG>` tag then you should neither use `content:///` nor `file:///`. In the latest version of Cordova, only `cdvfile://` protocol will work in HTML. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md

Comment: Hi, I had tried the above solution, but it will not work with the android version 4.1, I am able to retrieve the actual file location now by making use of the resolveLocalFileSystemURL which will convert the content://// to the file:/// url but that is the actual file url, file-transfer plugin require the cached file reference which can be persistent to do the upload, so now i am struck with getting the cached file reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload image using file-transfer phonegap plugin.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

You can use this code for upload image process

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
<!– WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 –>
<meta content=
"user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"
name="viewport">
<script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Camera Cordova Plugin</title>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button><br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo
Library</button><br>
<img id="image" src="" style="display:none;width:100%;">
<button onclick="upload();">Upload</button>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
function upload() {
    var img = document.getElementById('image');
    var imageURI = img.src;
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    var params = new Object();
    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, "https://www.example.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
}

function win(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
}
```

reference: http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/07/12/upload-image-using-file-transfer-cordova-plugin-for-ios-and-android/

my sample app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.revivalx.PayNow

Enjoy!!

Comment: Hi, I had tried the above solution, but it will not work with the android version 4.1, I am able to retrieve the actual file location now by making use of the resolveLocalFileSystemURL which will convert the content://// to the file:/// url but that is the actual file url, file-transfer plugin require the cached file reference which can be persistent to do the upload, so now i am struck with getting the cached file reference.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this plugin, an extension of the cordova-imagePicker:

https://github.com/ratkop/-cordova-imagePickerEx

> "...it returns a double array, if you select 10 photos it will return array of 20 files- half are optimized and half are the actual images"

This should allow you to reference the file locally for display as well as upload.